# How can I fix the error "cannot move out of dereference" without dereferencing pointers all the time?

Tags: pointers, rust

I just finished reading the lifetime guide on rust-lang.org and tried to implement the example (but with a generic enum to add a little complexity).

```
enum PositionInfo<T> {
    Position(T, T),
}

enum ShapeInfo<T> {
    RectInfo(T, T),
    CircleInfo(T),
}

enum GeometricObject<T>{
    Circle(PositionInfo<T>, ShapeInfo<T>),
    Rectangle(PositionInfo<T>, ShapeInfo<T>),
}

impl<T:Num> GeometricObject<T>{
    fn get_area(&self) -> Option<T> {
        match *self {
            Circle(_, CircleInfo(r))     => Some(r * r), 
            Rectangle(_, RectInfo(w, h)) => Some(w * h),
            _                            => None,
        }
    }
}
```

when I tried to compile the code, I get the following error

```
enum_tut.rs:28:9: 28:14 error: cannot move out of dereference of `&`-pointer
enum_tut.rs:28      match *self {
                          ^~~~~
enum_tut.rs:29:29: 29:30 note: attempting to move value to here (to prevent the move, use `ref r` or `ref mut r` to capture value by reference)
enum_tut.rs:29                 Circle(_, CircleInfo(r))     => Some(r * r), 
                                                    ^
enum_tut.rs:30:30: 30:31 note: and here (use `ref w` or `ref mut w`)
enum_tut.rs:30                 Rectangle(_, RectInfo(w, h)) => Some(w * h),
                                                     ^
enum_tut.rs:30:33: 30:34 note: and here (use `ref h` or `ref mut h`)
enum_tut.rs:30                 Rectangle(_, RectInfo(w, h)) => Some(w * h),
                                                        ^
error: aborting due to previous error
```

looking at the error message, I rewrote the implementation as the following and it compiled without any error.

This code looks cluttered; I have to dereference 4 pointers after I explicitly asked for it's reference.

Is there any way to write the code more cleanly?

```
impl<T:Num> GeometricObject<T>{
    fn get_area(&self) -> Option<T> {
        match *self {
            Circle(_, CircleInfo(ref r))         => Some(*r * *r), 
            Rectangle(_, RectInfo(ref w, ref h)) => Some(*w * *h),
            _                                    => None,
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that the lifetimes guide has been subsumed into the [Ownership guide](http://doc.rust-lang.org/guide-ownership.html) and, in somewhat-recent compiler versions, you'll need to make `GeometricObject`, `Circle`, `CircleInfo`, `Rectangle`, `RectInfo` as `Copy` to be able to match on `*self` like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your code doesn't know that it's safe to make a copy of `T` because you haven't told it so. The only safe thing is to have references to the object and dereference them. Otherwise, you might cause resource leaks or break safety guarantees.

Try this (the playpen isn't working right now, so I can't verify it...):

**Rust 1.0**

```
impl<T> GeometricObject<T>
    where T: Copy + std::ops::Mul<Output=T>
{
    fn get_area(&self) -> Option<T> {
        use GeometricObject::*;
        use ShapeInfo::*;

        match *self {
            Circle(_, CircleInfo(r))     => Some(r * r), 
            Rectangle(_, RectInfo(w, h)) => Some(w * h),
            _                            => None,
        }
    }
}
```

**Original**

```
impl<T:Num+Copy> GeometricObject<T>{
    fn get_area(&self) -> Option<T> {
        match *self {
            Circle(_, CircleInfo(r))     => Some(r * r), 
            Rectangle(_, RectInfo(w, h)) => Some(w * h),
            _                            => None,
        }
    }
}
```